# Resetting rectangle position using Timer in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jpanel

Im trying a small test on `Timer` animation in Java. Where there are three buttons and a rectangle. The buttons are `START` `STOP` `RESET` . When the start button is click the rectangle animates,when clicking the Stop,the rectangle stops animating and when clicking the reset button the rectangle should go back to the original position and only on clicking the Start it should start animating again. The first two button works! But the problem is in the `RESET` button. Here is my code,Please guide me where am I going wrong.

```
package projectretrytest;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ProjectRetryTest extends JPanel {

    private static final int D_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int D_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int INCREMENT = 8;
    int recx = 150,recy = 150;
    private Timer timer = null;

    public ProjectRetryTest() {

        timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                update();   
                repaint();
            }
        });
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                timer.start();
            }
        });
        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               timer.stop();
            }
        });

        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                recx = 150; recy = 150;

            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(start);
        panel.add(stop);
        panel.add(reset);
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
    public void update()
                {
                    recx++;
                    recy--;
                }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(recx,recy,20,20);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_WIDTH, D_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ProjectRetryTest());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And please let me know about the structuring of my program. Do I need to do some changes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the repaint() method like this :

```
 JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                recx = 150; recy = 150;
                repaint();
            }
        });
```

Also as mentioned in an other answer, you have to stop the Timer before Repainting your Graphics.

`Repaint()` : Will update your drawings, because changing the values is not enough to update what actually the user see on the interface.

Stopping The Timer : if the User wants to reset the drawings after starting the timer, the rectangle will go back to its initial state but it will keep moving, That's why stopping the timer in this case is a MUST.

Answer (score 1):

The reset listener should also stop the timer!  So this part of the action performed method..

```
recx = 150; recy = 150;
```

Should be more like:

```
recx = 150; recy = 150;
timer.stop(); // stop the animation..
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, why clicking on Reset is not working is that the UI is not repainted at that moment.
Simply add a `repaint()` into the listener and it will work.

```
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            recx = 150; recy = 150;
            repaint(); //<--this one is needed
        }
    });
```